# why do these similiar functions not work?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have some divs and if i hover them I want an popup to show. I have six divs and six popups to show but not all at once instead only one per one.

The first function works fine but then the other do not work how can I move them all to one snippet?

```html
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    let elements = document.querySelectorAll('#Mitarbeiter1Punkt');
    let popupposts = ['647'];
    elements.forEach(function(e, i) {
      e.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
        elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.showPopup({
          id: popupposts[i]
        });
      });

      e.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(event) {
        jQuery('body').click();
      });
    });
  });

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    let elements = document.querySelectorAll('#Mitarbeiter2Punkt');
    let popupposts = ['656'];
    elements.forEach(function(e, i) {
      e.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
        elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.showPopup({
          id: popupposts[i]
        });
      });

      e.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(event) {
        jQuery('body').click();
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('#Mitarbeiter2Punkt')` - That already doesn't make any sense.  An `id` needs to be unique.  If you're expecting to operate on multiple elements with the same `id` then your HTML is invalid.  Before trying to correct the JavaScript, correct the HTML that the JavaScript uses.

Comment: @David True but it would still return all the elements that have the same ID if that's the case. Not likely to be the problem.

oli venöl, Your two functions should be one function that take parameters to behave differently instead of copy pasting them. Also not the problem

Comment: Whether the ID is the problem or not, it's bad form.

Comment: @RuanMendes Have you cofirmed that? I believe jQuery has an optimization to only return the first match of ID selectors, browsers might do the same thing.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/va32Lrmd/ (no spoilers...)

Comment: `popupposts` only has one element. So if `elements` has more than one, the other `popupposts[i]` won't find anything.

Comment: Depends on what `$("body").click()` does.  *Assuming* it closes any popups - if there's any sort of timeout/delay before closing then the 2nd popup will be shown before all are closed - thus closing the 2nd before it's open.   We need to see a complete snippet that *demonstrates* the issue.   See [mcve].

Comment: @Barmar I did! And freeedomn-m did too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay so actually i figgered it out myself:

```html
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    let elements = document.querySelectorAll( '.mitarbeiterPunkt' );
    let popupposts = [ '647', '656', '660', '664', '664', '668', '672']; 

    elements.forEach(function(e,i){
            e.addEventListener( 'mouseenter', function(){
            elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.showPopup( { id: popupposts[i] } );
        } );

        e.addEventListener( 'mouseleave', function(event){
            jQuery('body').click();
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use an array of objects that maps the div IDs to the popup IDs. Loop over the array and set up all the event listeners.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  let popupMap = [{
      div: '#Mitarbeiter1Punkt',
      popup: 647
    },
    {
      div: '#Mitarbeiter2Punkt',
      popup: 646
    }
  ];

  popupMap.forEach(({div, popup}) => {
    let e = document.querySelector(div);
    e.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.showPopup(popup));
    e.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => jQuery('body').click());
  });
});
```

Comment: This is excactly what i was looking for! A solution to put all into one snippet, but unfortunatelyI get this error with your solution: Uncaught SyntaxError: Malformed arrow function parameter list

Comment: I was missing a comma after `'mouseleave'`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative option would be to make this data-driven rather code-driven - ie the data is in the HTML, not the js.  And as you're using jquery already, make use of jquery.

It's unlikely this will fix the root-cause of your issue as that's not been established (still waiting for complete sample) - this is to show how to combine this into a single function that doesn't need to be changed as you add new HTML.

```js
$(".punkt").on("mouseenter", function() {
  var id = $(this).data("popup-id");
  $(".popup[data-popup-id='" + id + "']").show();
});
$(".punkt").on("mouseleave", function() {
  var id = $(this).data("popup-id");
  $(".popup[data-popup-id='" + id + "']").hide();
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid rebeccapurple;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.popup {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='punkt' data-popup-id='A'>
  1
</div>
<div class='punkt' data-popup-id='B'>
  2
</div>
<div class='popup' data-popup-id='A'>
  A
</div>
<div class='popup' data-popup-id='B'>
  B
</div>
```